# Оператор while в С++ (подсчёт оценок)

Tags: c++

Подскажите, где тут может быть ошибка?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // variables
    int t, c, a, g;

    // initial value of variables
    t = 0, c = 1;

    // input cycle, summation of estimates
    while (c <= 10)
    {

    cout << "estimates: ";
    cin >> g;

    if (g <= 100)
    {
        t += g;
        c += 1;
    }
    else
        cout << "estimates should be from 0 to 100n";

    }

    // we consider a GPA
    a = t / 10;
    cout << "average assessment: " << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Каким должен быть результат:

[image]

У меня же выводится вот такой результат:

[image]

Если приглядеться, то на втором рисунке выводятся только 8 оценок, а 9 и 10 идут в одну строчку, вместе со средней оценкой.

Comment: @Рома Прогер, я поверил еще раз в Win 7 и опять все работает. Попробуйте просто запустить Ваш "while podschet ocenok.exe" из командной строки. 

Что получится ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле *загадка*. И те, **кто не думая над вопросом** ***минусуют*** сами себя должны ***забанить !!!***

--

Я не поленился (Copy/Paste) и **у меня все работает как должно быть** (10 строк ввода, потом среднее в отдельной строке)

```
Windows XP, окошко командной строки, g++.exe (GCC) 3.4.5  (mingw-vista special r3)
```

[@Рома Прогер](/users/4716/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80), получается, что вопрос не про оператор while в С++, а про систему программирования, которую Вы используете. Что не делает его неуместным (или плохим).

Comment: > И те, кто не думая над вопросом минусуют сами себя должны забанить !!!

Поддерживаю.

Comment: @Рома Прогер, скажите, а какие значени Вы вводили последние 2 раза, чтобы получить подобный скрин? Похоже на то, что при проверке последние 2 раза Вы нажали ввод, Вы не пробовали проверить, чему в этих случаях равна *g* ?

Comment: В принципе хорошая идея, но 2 <Enter> ничего не поменяли, **а вот ^Z !!!** получилось, как у автора.

Видимо тут так собака и порылась...